# Anaconda Python installation is not detected in linux mint

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I'm us using Linux Mint 17.1. I have installed Anaconda Python following the installation procedures given in the official webpage of Anaconda, but the linux is not detecting the installation and it uses the default python. Please suggest some thing.

Comment: How you have installed Anaconda python?, Have you added anaconda python path in the PATH environment variable or tried to modify the .bashrc of your user account?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the Anaconda installation, you are asked

> Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda2 install location
>   to PATH in your /home/muenker/.bashrc ? [yes|no]

Under Linux, the default choice is "no", resulting in a system that doesn't "know" anything about Anaconda. When you type

> python

the python interpreter that comes with the Linux distribution is found. You could either:

- Choose yes, but that means the Anaconda python is used instead of the default python interpreter which could have some side effects with the operating system
- from your home directory call `anaconda2/bin/python` but this is not very convenient
- add the path to the Anaconda bin directory temporarily by using

  > export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH

There is some more info at

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/installing-anaconda-python-on-ubuntu]

Hope that helps!